# Servlet mapping: url pattern problems

Tags: spring-mvc, servlets

I'm trying to set up a servlet mapping so that urls in the form "/getFile/{fileId}" will be mapped by my DispatcherServlet "dispatcher".

If I set up my web.xml as below only "/getFile" will be mapped, I can't append the fileId or it breaks.

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/getFile</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So I would have thought that I should use

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/getFile/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

But this doesn't work at all.

The method I'm trying to call is

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/getFile/{documentId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(@PathVariable int documentId, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

    UserDB userDB = UserDBService.getUser(user.getUsername());

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Document document = DocumentService.getDocument(documentId);
    String extension = document.getExtension();
    try {
        String path = ApplicationPropertiesConstants.SAFESITE_DOCUMENTS_DIRECTORY + userDB.getSite().getId() + "\\" + documentId + "." + extension;
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(path);

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
        response.setContentType("image/png");
        org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());

        response.flushBuffer();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: it's not a duplicate as below because I do not have a servlet mapping of just "/". Thus there is no default fall back mapping.

My full mapping.

```
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>            
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/getFile/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Remove `/getFile` from your `@RequestMapping`

Comment: How would that help. Then my request from a file from the client won't be matched with anything.

Comment: Right now you got `/getFile/getFile/{documentId}` as mapping. `<servlet mapping>/<request mapping>`

Comment: Ok /getFile/getFile/{documentId} actually works. So I'm just going to use that. If I just get rid of /getFile/ it doesn't work. (I don't see how it could).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right so I fixed it by using the url

> /getFile/getFile/{documentId}

on my client side.